# Trouble Placing Negative Numbers in the Negative Area of Scatter Plot Graph

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, plotly

I am encountering difficulties while attempting to plot negative numbers in the negative area of a scatter plot graph using Plotly. Despite my efforts to adjust the y-axis scaling and coordinates, the negative values consistently appear in the positive area of the graph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scatter Plot</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scatterplot"></div>
    <script>
        function plotGraph(data) {
            // Create an array to hold traces for each row of coordinates
            const traces = [];
            
            // Define marker shapes cycle
            const markerShapes = ['circle', 'square', 'diamond', 'cross', 'x', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'triangle-left', 'triangle-right', 'pentagon'];
            
            let markerIndex = 0; // Start with the first shape
            let dataCounter = 0; // Counter to track data points
            
            // Iterate over each entry in the data
            data.forEach((entry, index) => {
                // Extract x and y values from the entry
                const coordinates = entry.data.map(coord => [parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1]), parseFloat(coord[2].split('e')[1])]); // Splitting the exponent
                
                // Generate x values as the index of the points within the row
                const xValues = Array.from(Array(coordinates.length).keys()).map(x => x + Math.random() * 0.5 - 0.25); // Apply jitter
                
                // Adjust y-values for negative numbers
                const adjustedYValues = coordinates.map(coord => {
                    const value = parseFloat(coord[1]) * Math.pow(10, coord[2]);
                    return coord[0] === '-' ? -value : value;
                });
                
                // Create a trace for the current entry
                const trace = {
                    x: xValues,
                    y: adjustedYValues,
                    mode: 'markers',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    name: `Occurrences: ${entry.occurrences}`,
                    marker: {
                        symbol: markerShapes[Math.floor(dataCounter / 10) % markerShapes.length], // Change marker shape every 10 data points
                        size: 10 // Adjust the size of the marker symbols
                    }
                };
                
                // Increment the counter
                dataCounter += adjustedYValues.length;
                
                // Add the trace to the traces array
                traces.push(trace);
            });
            
            // Define layout options
            const layout = {
                title: 'Scatter Plot',
                xaxis: {
                    title: 'Index within the Row'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    title: 'Coordinate Value'
                },
                height: 800, // Set the height to 800 pixels
                width: 1200 // Set the width to 1200 pixels
            };
            
            // Plot the graph
            Plotly.newPlot('scatterplot', traces, layout);
        }
        
        // Fetch data and plot the graph
        fetch('/data')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                plotGraph(data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the graph.json

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      [
        "1",
        "1",
        "e-04"
      ],
      [
        "1",
        "1",
        "e-05"
      ],
      [
        "1",
        "1",
        "e-06"
      ],
      [
        "1",
        "1",
        "e-07"
      ],
      [
        "-1",
        "1",
        "e-04"
      ],
      [
        "-1",
        "1",
        "e-05"
      ],
      [
        "-1",
        "1",
        "e-06"
      ]
    ],
    "occurrences": 2
  }
]
```

and the server.js

the graph maps the data by the first digit and the exponent #

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Serve static files from the public folder
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Read data from the JSON file
const rawData = fs.readFileSync('graph.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawData);

// Route to serve the JSON data
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json(data);
});

// Route to serve filtered data based on occurrence number
app.get('/filtered-data/:occurrence', (req, res) => {
    const occurrence = parseInt(req.params.occurrence);
    const filteredData = data.filter(entry => entry.occurrences === occurrence);
    res.json(filteredData);
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have tried various approaches, including adjusting the data format and layout settings, but have not been successful. Any guidance or suggestions on how to properly position negative numbers in the negative area of the scatter plot graph would be greatly appreciated. Thank you